# CodeIgniter 3.0 .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this `.htaccess` file which I use for Codeigniter 2.2.0 and works well when I use subdirectories in my controllers. But in Codeigniter 3.0 I'm unable to access my website through the link http://localhost/myproject

Althought, the following links work:

http://localhost/myproject/index.php/frontend/home

http://localhost/myproject/frontend/home

My route is well defined

```
 $route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/home/index';
```

And my `.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # activate URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine on

    # do not rewrite links to the documentation, assets and public files
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots\.txt)

    # do not rewrite for php files in the document root, robots.txt or the maintenance page
    RewriteCond $1 !^([^\..]+\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)

    # but rewrite everything else
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 index.php

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `$route['default_controller']` with codeigniter 3.0 you can not use sub folders any more.

> It was a bug in CI2 that allowed you to put folders in default route

For `$route['default_controller']` the controller has to be in main controllers location like below.

Any other controllers can still have sub folders but the default controller must be in first level of controllers.

```
application

application > controllers 

application > controllers > Home.php
```

Note: You need to have first letter of class and file name set as upper case like below.

Routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home/index';
```

If you need to use subfolders with `$route['default_controller']` in codeigniter 3 I would recommend using HMVC and that will allow you to have subfolder in `$route['default_controller']` in routes.

Note: HMVC only for CI3
https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads

Answer (score 0):

In godaddy first letter of all the controller class must be in uppercase. working 100% in codeigniter 3.0 ->

like : 
application > controllers > **H**ome.php